# Cannot get regular expression work correctly with new line

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I am using regular expression for preventing any html tags to be entered in text box on client side. It is:

```
[RegularExpression("^(?!.*<[^>]+>).*"
```

But when I want to have new line by enter key, it also triggers notification.
Any idea how to make it accept multi line input?

Comment: `"^(?![\s\S]*<[^>]+>)[\s\S]*"`

Comment: It doesn't accept "\s\S" : `Error CS1009 Unrecognized escape sequence`

Comment: You just must use a literal ``\`` symbol. Double it inside a string literal. `"^(?![\\s\\S]*<[^>]+>)[\\s\\S]*"`